# DALI - how do I get control gear that supports ballast status and lamp failure query?

Tags: dali

I'm new to DALI.

I wanted to buy lights that I could query to see if there is a lamp failure.  When purchasing control gear for these lights, how do I know that it supports this feature?  If it lists a specific DTx or IEC 62386 Part then do I know it supports that feature?  Which DTx and Parts support it?

This is a pre-purchase question; I'm not asking how to query a device that I already own to see if it has that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ballast Status (control gear status) and lamp failure reporting are mandatory features in all DALI control gear which controls lamps, even for Part 224 Integrated Light Source. But part 206 Conversion to DC voltage only indicates output analogue voltage at the correct level. And part 208 Switching Function cannot be expected to detect lamp status.

If you make sure your ballast is on the DALI-2 certified list at https://www.dali-alliance.org/products then you have an assurance that the feature has been tested.

Bear in mind that lamp failure detection is only guaranteed for complete lamp failure since it is difficult to detect partial lamp failure or degradation eg a small percentage of LEDs in a series if they are still passing current.